# Loss of precision in turning inputs from text tuples into floating point list

Tags: python

The current goal of my program is to take a text file, which is read line by line and then up to the last number, the line goes into a tuple.
So, if I had 1,2,3,a on the first line.

The tuple would now have ('1', '2', '3'). My goal is to then get the tuple of strings and convert them into floats.

All I want right now is to get the proper data, so the output should be something like : {(1, 2, 3): a} if 1,2,3,a was the only line in my program.

The program gathers each line from the text file, reads up to the length of the line minus three. After that it reads the item of the length of the line minus two and gets a letter, or a class value.

I then engage a for loop of temporary values in a tuple and then apply each element to a variable a.
I append the item a onto the list.

I assign the list to a dictionary as a key by making it a tuple. I assign the class value to that tuple.

The problem I am having is that once I reach into the tuple and try to seize a value the item loses precision.

For example, if there was 1, 1, 2, 4, 5,6 put into the program. The items will become  0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0

1 becomes 0.
2 stays 2. 
4 becomes 3.
6 becomes 5.

I don't know why this is happening.

Here is my code

```
import sys
import math
import struct

#Step 1 : First we must open the file and unpack our data
def input_file(input):
    vector = dict()
    t = ()
    list = []
    k = 0
    c_value = []
    fp = open(input, "r")
    for line in fp.readlines():
        t = line[0:len(line)-3].split(",")
        print(t)
        c_value = line[len(line)-2]
        for i in t:
            a = float(t.index(i))
            #print(a)
            list.append(a)
            print(list)
        vector[tuple(list)] = c_value
        list = list[0:-k]
        k = 0
    print(vector)


#Step 2 : We must make an exemplar function
def exemplar(vector):
    i = 0

def main():
    input_file(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I need the code to do is take the items from t, and turn each item into floats, put them onto a list and then take that list and put them onto a dictionary as key values.

Because above all things these values NEED to be floats.

You might be asking yourself: "Why not just take the tuple you have and put it as your key?" Well, they are strings and I need to change them into floats. However, when I turn the strings into floats,they end up losing precision for some reason.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: you're taking `a = float(t.index(i))` the **index** of the values themselves. That seems to be your issue. 1 doesn't "become" zero, 1 is located at 0th index.

Comment: You've got a fair bit going on there... could you provide a small sample of your input file and what the desired `vector` from that would be?

Comment: generic comments: (a) don't reuse names of builtins, it will only lead to heartache (e.g. don't use 'list' as the name of a list). (b) floats make poor dictionary keys. python hashes the key to do the lookup and you'll end up with things not matching that look to your eye like they should match - at the very least you'll want to round them before using them as keys.

Comment: @JonClements Sure! So an input would be the a textfile, and said textfile would be split at the line. The line 1,2,3 would become the tuple ('1', '2', '3') my goal is to turn that vector of tuples into floats.

Comment: @MATT_BOOTY You can [edit] your question to add the extra info... So if you could add 3/4 lines of input and then how your `vector` would look a the end? Basically, enough info. so someone can copy/paste your input into a file and also be able to compare the output is what you're expecting.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh understood, so can I still use the index function as long as I change somethng, or would I be better off using another function? I tried making a = float(t.index([i])) however, the compiler then says that ['1'] is not in list.

Comment: Do you know what the index gives? And do you know what you wanted to do?

Comment: the whole point of the indexing is to obtain the value from tuples and load them onto the list as floats.